# How can I define the current directory for the execution of the <jetty>-task?

Tags: java, ant, jetty

I use in my project the [Jetty-task](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Ant+Jetty+Plugin) to execute a webapp. Can I somehow set the working-directory used by Jetty as the servlet-container is started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can since the ant task runs jetty in the same VM and there is famously no way to set the current working directory for a running VM. You can try adding a system property for `user.dir` but that might not do quite what you want. You could also use the `apply` task to relaunch ant with a new working directory with a snippet like

```
<apply executable="${ant.home}/bin/ant" dir="/new/working/directory/here">
  <arg value="-f"/>
  <arg value="${ant.file}"/>
  <arg value="run-jetty"/>
</apply>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the `tempDirectory` attribute not do what you want?

Comment: No, that defines the directory used by jetty to save temporary data, but it is not the current working-directory.

Comment: What is jetty using the current directory for such that you want to change it?